# Using ui-router's resolve on a controller defined with inline array annotation and fluent API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm used to defining angular controllers with the [inline array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation), e.g.:

```
angular
  .controller('SomeCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    ...
}])
```

I also prefer the fluent API for angular modules, i.e. there is only a single `angular.module` call at the top of my file defining the controllers, and everything else is chained to this call.

I would now like to use ui-router's resolve feature, and keep the controller dependency with the controller, not in the router (see the [recommendations on routing resolves](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#routing-resolves)).

Is there a way to continue using my preferred approaches (inline array notation, fluent API) together with the recommendations for ui-router's resolve? My current understanding is that `angular.controller` defines the constructor for a controller, so in order to have an additional `resolve()` method on the controller I would have to pass in an object that already has this method plus a constructor.

Update: adding a code sample.

Route:

```
function config ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/myroute', {
    templateUrl: 'views/some.html',
    controller: 'SomeCtrl'
    resolve: SomeCtrl.resolve
  });
}
```

Controller:

```
angular
  .controller('SomeCtrl', [ '$scope', 'SomeService', function($scope, SomeService) {
    var data = SomeService.data;
...
}])
```

Where `SomeService.data()` is the method call that returns the promise I need resolved. How do I define the resolve using my preferred approaches?

```
SomeCtrl.resolve = {
  data: function(SomeService) {
    return SomeService.data();
  }
};
```

Comment: The question title references ui-router, but the body of the question is showing using ngRouter.  These are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using the inline annotations. You will just need an annotation for the name of the model that you are resolving.

So if your resolve has a method named getPromise, your inline controller DI annotation should contain the string 'getPromise'.

**UPDATE**

So with your code examples you should make the following changes.

Add 'resolve annotations' to your resolve object:

```
SomeCtrl.resolve = {

  'SomeService': SomeService,  

  someData: ['SomeService', function(SomeService) {
    return SomeService.data();
  }]
};
```

Add an annotation to the resolve method. I have changed it from 'data' in your example to 'someData' here:

```
angular
  .controller('SomeCtrl', [ '$scope', 'someData', function($scope, someData) {
     var data = someData;
     ...
}])
```

**Another UPDATE**

Ok. I think I understand the question now.

You do not need to define the uiRouter resolve with SomeCtrl.resolve.

You can define the resolve inline in the module config section:

```
function config ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/myroute', {
    templateUrl: 'views/some.html',
    controller: 'SomeCtrl'
    resolve:  {
           'SomeService': SomeService,  
           someData: ['SomeService', function(SomeService) {
               return SomeService.data();
           }]
       }
  });
}
```

Or if you want to get fancy, you can create a resolve object with keys for each of your state and then do some thing like:

```
...
resolve: myResolveObj.someState
...
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a code sample. Could you elaborate on your answer based on it?

Comment: Thnks for updating your answer. If I understand it correctly, this provides the mapping for the service that returns the model using inline array notation. My question is about not having SomeCtrl.resolve = ... in the code, as it breaks the fluent API style definition of the controller. Do you know a way to move this into fluent API as well?